# how to click on anchor tag in c# using gecko browser engine

Tags: javascript, c#, gecko

I'm trying to click on the link that contains the text "Next".
I've tried this code in c# using gecko web browser engine:

```
Gecko.DOM.GeckoLinkElement next = new Gecko.DOM.GeckoLinkElement(geckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByClassName("single-prev-next")[0].LastChild.DomObject);

next.Click();
```

Here is the Html of the website :

```
<div class="single-prev-next" style="float:right">
<span class="picture-of">Photo 3 of 8 </span>
<div id="prevre">
</div>
<a href="http://website.com/to/150810/4/">Next</a>
</div>
```

That's not working at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, why not simply navigate to the value of the link?
i.e. `browser.Navigate("http://website.com/to/150810/4/");`

I don't think it will make any difference based on your page code sample and will be faster and easier.

If you need to click though...
This is not the way to do it - you are not actualy creating a new Link element after all.
Therefore, something along the lines

```
GeckoAnchorElement link =   (GeckoAnchorElement)browser.Document.GetElementsByClassName("single-prev-next")[0].LastChild;
link.Click();
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch dude!
By the way, the purpose I don't use navigate is because navigate removes  referrer property.

Comment: @CodyMan -  OK - however, you can specify the referrer. The .Navigate() method of the geckowebbrowser has an overload that accepts a referrer string. Cheers;)

Comment: I knew that already, by the way that increases the bounce rate for session